# iphone/ipad app not appearing in iPad app store

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, universal

We're developing our first iPhone and iPad app with xcode 4.5.2.  It is a universal app, with targeted device family = iPhone/iPad.  Runs fine on simulators for iPhone and iPad but when distributed to Apple it only shows up in the app store on the iPhone.  On the iPad app store . . . nothing.

When you search for it online you can get the iTunes page in the browser (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/episurveyor/id499388914?mt=8) but note that "Requirements: Compatible with iPhone 3G, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, and iPhone 5."  No listing of iPad.  If you do that search on iPad you can find the same page in Safari but it then launches the app store and says "The item you've requested is not currently available in the U.S. Store."

What setting are we missing?  I know this must be something very simple.

Comment: I have noticed that my iPhone only app does not always show up in the app store on an iPad even when you tap the iPhone.  I think it may be a glitch with Apple's new app store app.

Comment: Did you make sure the iPad app icon and screenshots were correctly assigned?

Comment: Have you checked the app status in iTunesConnect?

Comment: Please note, as I indicated in the question, that the app is showing up on the iPhones in the App Store -- so clearly the app has been approved for sale.  The icon and screenshots are correctly assigned, as well.  I don't think this is a glitch with the app store.  I think it is some setting in Xcode.

Comment: Same thing happening to us, a client called and said they couldn't find the app in iTunes from his iPad2, but it is there on my iPhone4 and a workmate's iPhone5.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved!  Apple told me it was because we had specified SMS as a required capability -- but the iPad doesn't have any SMS capability, so it assumed it could not run on the iPad.  Removed the SMS requirement and have resubmitted.